# Collection state seems to stay after leaving scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have some special properties on a backbone.js collection. I came up with a simple example to try and illustrate:

```
TestCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    properties: {
        something: 'foo',
        other: 'bar'
    }
});
```

Say that `test` is a route that is called when the url `#test` is hit. It runs this method.

```
test: function(){
    var c = new TestCollection();
    console.log(c.properties.something);
    c.properties.something = 'changed';
},
```

If I then visit a different hash, say `#anythingelse`, and then go back to `#test`, the console still logs `"changed"`, rather than the value of `"foo"`. I need the state to be "reset" when the collection is created. Why is the state staying around when I have a local variable? I've tried some things like `_.clone` to try and "backup" some properties and have them be retrieved in an initialization function, but I haven't succeeded in that yet. I'm hoping I'm just totally misunderstanding something and that there's a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

All of your TestCollection instances will end up sharing exactly the same `properties` value because there's no deep copying going on; in fact, as [ggozad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644388/ggozad) notes below, there is no copying going on at all as `properties` is attached to the prototype rather than the instance. For example, this will give you three `pancakes` in your console because all three instances share exactly the same `{something: '...'}` object in their `properties`:

```
TestCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    properties: {
        something: 'foo'
    },
    m: function(x) {
        this.properties.something = x;
    }
});
var t1 = new TestCollection();
var t2 = new TestCollection();

t1.m('pancakes');
console.log(t1.properties.something);
console.log(t2.properties.something);

var t3 = new TestCollection();
console.log(t3.properties.something);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hBeHU/

An easy way out of this dilemma is to move your `properties` into the collection's `initialize`:

```
TestCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.properties = {
            something: 'foo'
        };
    },
    m: function(x) {
        this.properties.something = x;
    }
});
```

If you use this version of `TestCollection` then you'll get one `pancakes` and two `foo`s in your console.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/GywKF/

Comment: Just to point out that whether all `TestCollection` instances have a common `properties` attribute is not related to deep copying. In your first example by defining `properties` on `extend` you add it to `TestCollection.prototype` making a single reference available to all instances of TestCollection, whereas on your second example you create it per TestCollection instance.

Comment: @ggozad: Right, the OP is expecting `properties` to be deep copied into each instance when it isn't being copied at all. I've tried to clarify that.